# Calculate distance between two location Angular 2 Google Maps Api inline template:10:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'spherical' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to calculate distance between 2 locations in a angular 2 app using google maps API.

Here are my import to use google map api

`

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from "@agm/core";
```

Then I created a function to test a distance calculation

`

```
calculateDistance() {
    const nyc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.715, -74.002);
    const london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.506, -0.119);
    const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(nyc, london);
    console.log(distance)
  }
```

`

But I get this error:
inline template:10:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'spherical' of undefined.

I've seen some answers that suggest to add this script tag

But when I try this I get an other error that says that I'm trying to add google mpa api more than once and it may cause some errors (it does, autocompletion does not work anymore when I import this script tag).

Answer (score 1):

in your app.module, where you init your google api key add this "libraries=geometry" for example in my case:

apiUrl: 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY'

I'm using ng2-ui/map

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md

Answer (score 1):

add the geometry library to your module

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: '',
  libraries: ['geometry']
}),
```